# Check value of one item of tuple from other item

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I have a list of tuples like

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> tuple = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "10"));
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(2, "20"));
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(3, "30"));
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(4, "None"));
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(5, "None"));
```

There is another list which contains the ids which is actually the item 1 of above tuple.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>():
```

List contains 2 values

```
list.Add(1);
list.Add(4);
```

I have to compare the items of list with item 1 of tuple and get the value of item 2 of the tuple when the value of item 2 is not `"None"`. In cases where the value of item 2 is none in those cases use item 1 only.

Comment: What is the problem? What did you try to solve it and what didn't work of them?

Comment: didn't understand your problem statement. just mumbling item,item,item,list..make it simple to understand

Comment: I have used simple foreach loop but i want it using linq.

Comment: please, share the `foreach` solution

Comment: Show us the for-loop, it is quite hard to grasp what you want from the last paragraph.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: In simplified way first  I will  check the id equal to 1 of list in tuple of item 1.It is present therefore then I will check its corresponding item 2 which is 10.Therefore return value 10. Same is for 2 and 3 for which value of item 2 is 20 and 30 which will be returned.For id 4 and 5 value of item 2 is None therefore in this case not item 2 but item 1 itself will be returned which is 4 and 5.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the LINQ:

```
tuple
    .Where(x => list.Contains(x.Item1))
    .Select(x => x.Item2 == "None"
        ? x.Item1
        : int.Parse(x.Item2));
```

Comment: I just deleted mine because it's the same thing. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: +1 for a clean and simple to understand LINQ answer, some error checking can be added as required (TryParse) but was not requested by OP

Answer (score 0):

You could also do an inner join:

```
var result= from e in list
            join t in tuple on e equals t.Item1
            select t.Item2=="None"?t.Item1:int.Parse(t.Item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If Item1 in the tuple list is going to be unique I would recommend using a dictionary.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

dict.Add(1, "10");
dict.Add(2, "20");
dict.Add(3, "30");
dict.Add(4, "None");
dict.Add(5, "None");

var list = new List<int>(){ 1, 4 };

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list.Select(i => dict[i] == "None" ? i.ToString() : dict[i])));
```

Comment: Actually u r right but actually i have more than 2 items in my case thats why using tuple

Comment: @Remon A `Dictionary<int, Tuple<...>>` can still be used in your case. However, you should consider changing that into a class. Since `Item1` and `Item2` are not really descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> tuple = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "10"));
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(2, "20"));
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(3, "30"));
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(4, "None"));
tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(5, "None"));
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(4);

var result = tuple.Join(list, t => t.Item1, l => l, 
            (t,l) => t.Item2 == "None" ? t.Item1.ToString() : t.Item2)
            .ToList();
```